# How to scrape href using bs4 and Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the "href" links from the page, but the result is "none", can you please help me find where my code is going wrong? why is the code returning "none"?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

res = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/newest')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('.titleline')


def fit_hn(links):
    hn = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(links):
        href = links[idx].get('href')
        hn.append(href)
    return hn


pprint.pprint(fit_hn(links))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a deeper look.
if you were to print `links`, you'll see that it's returning the `span` with the `a`:

```html
<span class="titleline"><a href="https://longreads.com/2023/01/03/the-strangely-beautiful-experience-of-google-reviews/" rel="nofollow">The Strangely Beautiful Experience of Google Reviews</a><span class="sitebit comhead"> (<a href="from?site=longreads.com"><span class="sitestr">longreads.com</span></a>)</span></span>
```

So, really you need to go one level deeper and select the `<a>` tag.
Change your CSS selector to also select the `a` tags:

```
links = soup.select('.titleline a')
```

Your above code now prints:

```
['https://www.the-sun.com/tech/7078358/xoxe-ai-woman-detects-anxiety-and-crime-afterlife/',
 'from?site=the-sun.com',
 'https://www.economist.com/business/2023/01/05/how-to-avoid-flight-chaos',
 'from?site=economist.com',
 'https://www.thegutterreview.com/but-who-is-the-artist-the-kenny-who-trilogy-and-the-reality-of-ai-art/',
 'from?site=thegutterreview.com',
 'https://twitter.com/jburnmurdoch/status/1606223967903260673',
 'from?site=twitter.com/jburnmurdoch',
 'https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/01/newest-raspberry-pi-camera-module-3-adds-autofocus-wide-view-hdr/',
```